Banking for digital nomad
I am planning to travel for a long time, maybe staying somewhere for a couple of years, don't know yet. Basically living the life of a digital nomad for an extended period of time.
As such, the question arises - what facility to use for banking purposes? Every single option that I checked requires residential address and I suspect might at some point request for some proofs of residency at the address specified.
But if I no longer live there and probably am a half the world away, what can I do? There are reports of Wise doing it to some people.
There is an option to keep paying some bills at my last address of registration and ask current residents to send me scans of the bills but it is so much headache.
Is there a totally legal system which gives you access to banking services not requiring residential address? Seriously looking into cryptocurrencies at this point, so tired.

What's wrong with the bank you're using now?

@littleadv they told me they do not allow non residents to have an account with them.

You might try the expats stack; this seems to be on their area of expertise.

Product recommendations are off topic here. But, fwiw, I have bank accounts from a couple of decades ago in a couple of countries, which send no mail and work fine wherever I am. They do need to know my tax status, and may be that would be the main obstacle for you, but that's a different issue.

Cross post here: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/27396/banking-for-digital-nomad-expat

What is your country of citizenship? If it's the United States, it is possible to establish residency in certain states that facilitate banking, mail forwarding and taxes for expats. South Dakota is a good example.
You do need to physically go to South Dakota to set it all up, and from there you can travel the world. An online search for "South Dakota residency for expats" has a number of articles and resources you can peruse.
Advantages:

You can establish residency and obtain an id/driver license with just
one overnight stay.
no state income tax
plenty of mail forwarding services available
easy to establish a bank account to use while full-time traveling.


I am in Australia, here you live where you say you live :) The question is how to handle it in the future if you have to use the address to receive correspondence or have to prove that you actually live there.
